# is there a way to hide a member of a Superclass from the derived class?

Tags: java

I'm curious if it's possible to declare a member of a class such that it not be exposed to the derived class either at all, or at least until the subclass calls `super()`. Is there such a feature in Java?

```
 class A{
      static int foo = 1;
    }

    class B extends A{
      public B(){
         System.out.print(foo);/// how do I make this not work?
      }
    }
```

Edit: I actually typed my question with the solution, by accident (my actual code was missing the private). So I'll edit my question and remove the private so that it's a meaningful question :)

Comment: You've already made `foo` invisible to `B` because you marked it as `private` in `A`.

Comment: It looks like you want something that works as private until you use `super.somethingHere`, right? Well, this isn't possible. The only solution would be using `protected` so only children classes could access to parent class field/methods.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is possible in one situation: if A and B share the same top level class. B can access `super.foo`, but not `foo`

Comment: @zhong.j.yu this is an inheritance question, but you're talking about inner classes. Yes, you can do that in an inner class because the class its like an attribute of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That already won't work - the member is private, so isn't visible from B.

However, if you're trying to hide an already-visible member in a subclass, e.g.

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
        // Whatever
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    // ???
}

...
B b = new B();
b.foo(); // I don't want this to work, because it's a B!
```

... then you can't do that. It would break [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: That's really funny, Jon. I had the code missing the private in my actual code and accidentally constructed my question to have the solution built in! :) Thanks.

Comment: You could always override `foo` in B to throw an error (if you really wanted to).

Comment: @sdasdadas: Yes, but that's not really the same thing - and it would have to be a runtime exception (or some exception already declared in the base class).

Answer (score 2):

One interpretation of the question is that you want accessing `foo` to fail, but accessing `super.foo` to succeed. It can happen in one particular situation - if both A and B are enclosed in the same top level class, or one of them is the top level class enclosing the other.

```
class X

    class A  
        private int foo;

    class B extends A

        print(foo);           // fail
        print(super.foo);     // ok  
        print(((A)this).foo); // ok...
```

or

```
class A
    private int foo;

    static class B extends A    // declared inside A

        print(foo);           // fail
        print(super.foo);     // ok  
        print(((A)this).foo); // ok...
```

The reason is that  that private members are not inherited, so `this.foo` doesn't exist; but they are accessible throughout the top level class, with proper qualifier, so `A.foo` is accessible. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1-100-D-3

Comment: in my situation B is not declared inside A, but that's really good to know!, thanks.

Comment: The second code block won't fail when you said it would. This is because non-static inner classes can access to attributes in the top class, somewhat you're misleading OP without adding this info.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes should be static. I haven't tested the code, but the general idea is that `private` members are not inherited, but they are accessible throughout the top level class.

Comment: Because...? With no explanation, it's like saying *the sky is blue because the sky is blue*. And please, provide code that works (can compile), it would be better to test it before posting it, otherwise don't post an answer at all.

Comment: Then try to explain a reason when somebody asks you that instead of just saying *because it is* =\. Please refer to [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442975/1065197) to understand the difference between your answer and a good one.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've just tested the 2 examples and verified that they are correct. The explanation is added. Now my answer is a good one, and better than Jon's, because you learned something from mine, didn't you?:)

Comment: No I don't learn anything new here (since I know inner classes stuff), but maybe OP does. I don't think your answer is better than Jon's, you just saw the question from another point of view and added something different.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the variable as `private` then a subclass won't have access to it.

(Also, you probably don't want `static` in your foo declaration.)

Comment: actually I do... but I see why without more context it might seem peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

The access modifiers (e.g. declaring the member to be `private`) is the only thing that will actually prevent access to a member.  (And even then, you can use reflection to get hold of the private member anyway.)

---

When you mention `super`, you might be thinking of using *hiding* in the Java sense; e.g. where you declare something else called `foo` to hide the original declaration.  However it won't help here.

- You would have to declare the 2nd `foo` in `B` or some subclass `C` such than `A` ... extends `C` ... extends `B`.
- Since these are statics, `B` can always access the original `foo` as `A.foo`.  Indeed, since `<class>.<name>` is the recommended approach, this (hypothetical) use of hiding has not achieved anything worthwhile (IMO).
- Even to the extent that it does work, it simply replaces one `foo` with another `foo`, which isn't what your use-case requires.

In short *hiding* is not an effective means of reducing or controlling exposure.